# How can I load my workspace from my start menu GUI in ROBLOX?

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, lua, roblox, startmenu

I'm making a ROBLOX game, and I've got a GUI issue:

- I've got a "Start Game" button, but I have it in an elif statement to where it just toggles from "Start Game" to "Game Loading..." back and forth when you click it. How can I change it so instead of saying "Game Loading...", when you click it, it transitions into the actual game (my workspace)?

I don't even want "Game Loading..." to show up, I only put it there when I was learning the ins and outs of buttons.

My GUI is just the start menu, so when you click Start Game, the GUI should go away and you'd be loaded into the actual game.

Here's what I've got for the script for the button:

```
local button = script.Parent
local toggled = false

local function onButtonActivated()
    if toggled == false then
        button.Text = "Game Loading..."
        toggled = true
    else
        button.Text = "Start Game"
        toggled = false
    end
end

button.Activated:Connect(onButtonActivated)
```

Note: I'm using Lua (ROBLOX's default language) via IntelliJ and just copy-pasting my finished code into the scripts, since IntelliJ has a much better text editor than ROBLOX's default one.

Answer (score 0):

If this place is just a hub with the start menu, and the *actual* game is elsewhere in the universe, then you'll need to use [`TeleportService:Teleport()`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TeleportService/Teleport) to move the `LocalPlayer` to that game. After the teleport is done, the player would be able to play that game with no issues. Here's an example using your code sample:

```lua
local button = script.Parent
local toggled = false
local destination = 0 -- Change 0 to the place ID you want the user to be teleported to
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")

local function onButtonActivated()
    if toggled == false then
        button.Text = "Game Loading..."
        --toggled = true
        TeleportService:Teleport(destination)
    else
        button.Text = "Start Game"
        toggled = false
    end
end

button.Activated:Connect(onButtonActivated)
```

However, if you're loading this GUI inside of the *actual* game, all you need to do is [`:Destroy()`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/Destroy) the GUI object. This will permenantly move the GUI object and all of its children under `nil`, and disconnect all connections.

In the game, this will mean that the GUI simply disappears, and the player will be able to continue playing the game. Unless you have other critical code running inside the GUI, this should be the go-to solution if you're working with just one place.

```lua
local button = script.Parent
local toggled = false
local guiObj = nil -- Replace nil with a reference to the "ScreenGui/BillboardGUI" object that houses the 'button'.

local function onButtonActivated()
    if toggled == false then
        --[[button.Text = "Game Loading..."
        toggled = true]]--
        guiObj:Destroy()
    else
        button.Text = "Start Game"
        toggled = false
    end
end

button.Activated:Connect(onButtonActivated)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, even still, when I click Start Game, nothing happens.

Comment: @Stealth Are there any errors that show up in the Developer Console? And so we can help you better, what method did you use? (`Destroy` or `Teleport`?)

Comment: No errors that I know off. IntelliJ wants me to just remove the "-- nil" because it's "unnecessary italics", but even then it doesn't work. Oh, and also, I used Destroy.

Answer (score 0):

```
local button = script.Parent
local guiObj = --a reference to the main screengui which the button is a descendant of

local function onButtonClicked()
    guiObj:Destroy()
end

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(onButtonClicked)
```

You could do some fancy fading and stuff if you want to.